# Perform a "Union" of two tables using "join" operator

Tags: sql, join, union

The question being asked is not a practical one but rather a logical one.

Lets suggest we have to tables  A (ID_A, A_Name) and B (ID_B, B_Name, ID_A)

If I run something like

```
 select A_Name from A
        union
 select B_Name from B
```

The result will be something as follows (not taking in the account the sorting):

```
  A_Name1
  A_Name2
  A_Name3
  B_Name1
  B_Name2
  B_Name3
```

Qustion: How can I get the SAME result (a single column that combines all the A_Names and B_Names) using only JOIN operators, WITHOUT using UNION ?

Comment: As I've explained - it's just a logical problem with no real-world value. I know that there is a way to do such thing - thus I am trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(A.A_Name, B.B_Name)
from A full join B on 1=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FULL outer join to get the result

```
select case when nameA is null then  nameB else nameA end as UNIONNAME 
from 
tableA
full outer join 
tableB
on nameA=nameB
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d60f1/2)**:

Answer (score 1):

you can use this SELECT:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_Name, '') <> '' THEN A_Name ELSE B_Name END AS Name
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A_Name = B_Name
```